# <could usage> She could be very unkind

Tags: could-modal

> She **could** be very unkind.

In the above sentence, what is this "could" usage?
I mean, this could has a similar meaning to "would"(would do something used for talking about things that often happened in the past), hasn't it???

According to YBM dictionary, this sentence means there was a time when she was very unkind. But I am not sure this translation is correct or not.

Note - YBM is a Korean company that publishes English books, dictionaries and so on. So I cannot completely trust it more than Oxford or Longman.

Comment: It's a "hedge", where the speaker is "toning down" the underlying assertion *She **was** very unkind*.

Comment: could here: there were times when she was unkind.

Comment: her unkindness is in the past - maybe she is a kind person now, or maybe she just is no longer around

Comment: Hi Lambie and Justin, so is this <could usage> similar to <would usage>?

Comment: In the relevant contexts, <would> implies ***often, habitually*** where <could> implies ***sometimes***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost I interpret it as saying she was unkind on more than one occasion in the past, and thus provably had the capacity to be unkind.  In fact, she may have been very unkind, and the speaker is downplaying her great unkindness in an ironic way - and his listener is somewhat likely to already know about this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really correct to say ***could*** "means" ***had the capability*** in such contexts. That's like saying ***Can you tell me the time**?* is asking about your ***ability***, which clearly isn't the intended sense. So far as I'm concerned, the idiomatic usage *He **can be** rude sometimes* is just a very slightly "hedged / softened" way of saying *He **is** rude sometimes* (much like asking ***Would** you help me?* instead of ***Will** you help?*, where the speaker wants to place some "distance" between himself and the "true" meaning of an utterance).

Comment: does it necessarily mean she was unkind in the past (on at least one occasion)? could it be just an instance of generalisation as in "a human being could be unkind"?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: It always applies to the one specific individual, and it always means ***on more than one occasion in the past***.

Comment: I'll edit it.  Thanks @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica

Comment: Well, I already upvoted because the answer was substantially correct. But if I could upvote ***again*** now I would - specifically because of that reference to ***downplaying***, which I think hits the nail on the head with this particular usage.

Comment: I swapped in "capacity" for capability, in case that escaped your attention :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Hi, above all, thank you so much. Additionally I am wondering whether this <could usage> similar to <would usage> or not.